# Bootstrap button linked to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
<h1>List of products</h1>
<%= link_to 'Download as .xlsx', products_path(format: :xlsx) %>
```

I have the above lines of code in my application.html.erb. So when I click on the hyperlink `"Download as .xlsx"` in my Rails application, I would be routed to `products_path` which has the code to generate an excel. This works perfectly for me.

Now, I would like to replace the hyperlink above with a bootstrap button. So when I click on the button, I need to be routed to `products_path` as well.

How do I achieve that? Please help!

Comment: No need to replace it. Just add `class: "btn btn-primary"` to look like a button

Answer (score 0):

[button_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

```
<%= button_to "Download as .xlsx", products_path(format: :xlsx), :id => "my_id", :class=> "btn btn-default", :method => :get %>
```

You can use different [bootstrap button class](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp) to make it more cosmetic

Add `:method => :get` Without it, the button_to will generate a `form` with method set to `post`.

Updated: -
To make it dynamic

```
<%= link_to products_path(format: :xlsx) do%>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download as xlsx</button>
<%end%>
```

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
How can I invoke products_path defined in routes.rb from this button? Please help!

Comment: @Biju Check the updated answer, you can wrap button into link_to.. do . hope it's clear to you.